# Polymer 'detail.item' won't return the correct object

Tags: javascript, polymer

I can't for the love of god get selection (or animated-pages for that matter) to work. I tried following the tutorials, but they don't mention ANYWHERE how to actually perform the transition from one page to another (or there is something I'm totally not understanding), my guess is that I should only need to set the `selected` value of the `core-animated-pages` but that doesn't work either.

First of all, the `detail.item` object doesn't seem to contain the correct stuff. I'm probably doing something trivial wrong. When trying to access "detail.item.selectedIndex" from the `on-core-select` event I only get `undefined`. If I access the property by id using: `this.$.selector.selectedIndex` it will work.

Also doing the following seems to do nothing:

```
var pages = this.$.pages;
pages.selected = selectedIndex;
```

See the code below to understand what I'm trying to do:

```
<!-- 2. Load the component using an HTML Import -->
... Imports here ...

<polymer-element name='index-app'>
  <template>
    <core-scaffold>
      <core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
        <core-toolbar>Application</core-toolbar>
        <core-menu theme="core-light-theme" >
          <core-selector on-core-select="{{selectAction}}" id="selector">
            <core-item icon="settings" label="item1"></core-item>
            <core-item icon="settings" label="item2"></core-item>
          </core-selector>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>
      <div tool>{{item.label}}</div>
      <div class="content">
        <core-animated-pages transitions="cross-fade-all" id="pages" selected="{{selected}}">
          <section id="page1" hidden?="{{selected!=0}}">
            <div cross-fade>Home page contents</div>
          </section>
          <section id="page2" hidden?="{{selected!=1}}">
            <div cross-fade>Gallery contents</div>
          </section>
        </core-animated-pages>
      </div>
    </core-scaffold>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function(){
        this.$.selector.selected = 0;
      },
      selectAction: function(e, detail){
        var selectedIndex = this.$.selector.selectedIndex;
        var pages = this.$.pages;
        pages.selected = selectedIndex;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using selected={{selection}} for both your core selector and your core animated pages. If I remember correctly, the `selected` published property binds to the index of the item for both of these elements. In your core selector it will bind to the index of the item that has been selected, and in the core animated pages will pull the bound value and use it as the index to grab the page and display that page.

In other words, you don't need an event handler or manual manipulation of the hidden element. The data binding system handles this all for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean selected={{selected}} or do you actually mean selected={{selection}}? EDIT: It seems "selected={{selected}}" works _kinda_. The value is correctly shown, but the pages is neither swapped not animated, in other words: both pages are shown. :/

Comment: Sorry, I meant selected. I am currently on my mobile device but I will look at this in more detail when I am at a workstation

Comment: Thank you! You're answer helped me solve (and understand) the issue and also figure out why the rest didn't work. I had forgotten to "import" the _core-animated-pages_ That's why the transition didn't work (feeling embarrassed)! :(